# Admin form redirect to dashboard - Magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, forms, adminform

I am trying to store the value in custom table from admin form but it is always redirect to admin dashboard when I submit the form.

**form page admin url:** `http://magentodev.gworks.mobi/magento2/admin/gworksrc/cancel/`

```
<form action="/magento2/admin/gworksrc/cancel/" method="post">
 <input type="number" name="timeinterval" id="timeinterval" />
 <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="timesubmit" />
</form>
```

I have tried with various type of action URL but nothing work

```
 action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>
 action=""
 action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('gworksrc/cancel/index'); ?>"
```

I found the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604143/magento-admin-form-redirects-to-dashboard-on-post), but it is syntax error but my form look simple I can't found any syntax error.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You form must have form key to allow submit data.
See [formkey.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/formkey.phtml) that used in core forms

Answer (score 0):

Use this, I hope this is use full for you,

```
 action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('gworksrc/cancel'); ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

After put some efforts found solution.

In admin form you should need to add one hidden form input tag for carry session otherwise it redirects to admin dashboard page.

**FormKey**

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->updateCancelTime() ?>" />
```

Admin Form Look Like below

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('gworksrc/cancel'); ?>" method="post">
 <input type="number" name="timeinterval" id="timeinterval" />
 <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="timesubmit" />
 <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->updateCancelTime() ?>" />
</form>
```

**Admin Block for return form key**

```
public function updateCancelTime(){

    return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
}
```

**Reference:** http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/09/13/magento-submitting-form-in-admin-redirects-to-dashboard/

above URL for Magento 1.X, I could covert into Magento 2