# magento 2 simple admin form with submit and without any data source

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminform

Trying to create simple form inside admin to perform some action inside Block class (included into layout) and return success or error message.

The thing is I needn't use any data source and edit/delete actions.
So simply need to submit it and do some actions inside.

I tried to make form via template and layout, but submit takes me to "admin/dashboard" instead of needed controller whatever I tried to set inside form action parameter.

*view\adminhtml\templates\index\index.phtml*

```
<form class="form" action="" method="post">

    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Import Product') ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <label for="number" class="label">
                <span><?php echo __('GTIN') ?></span>
            </label>

            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="number"
                       name="number"
                       class="input-text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?php echo __('Submit') ?>">
                <span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

*view\adminhtml\layout\importproduct_index_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="admin-1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Modules\Import\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index" name="index.index"
                   template="Modules_Import::index/index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

How to make submit to needed controller? Or is there another way to create simple form?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/115857/36463

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure that you missed to add form key:

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Remember to add Url action for your form.

Code for `getFormKey()` taken here `vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Template.php`

Comment: Code for getFormKey() taken here vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Template.php

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh in my form, form key available and field's name attribute also available. Still, $this->getRequest()->getPostValue() return blank. Do you know solution about that?

Comment: I added form in browser model dialogue. Same as like Catalog -> Categories -> Content -> Select From Gallery.

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to set your form `action` URL. It looks like you are using Import feature so you have to also add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

In block file you can write

```
namespace Modules\Import\Block\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

    protected $_backendUrl;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl
    ) {

        $this->_backendUrl = $backendUrl;
    }
    public function getPostUrl()
    {
        $params = array('some'=>'url_parameters');

        $url = $this->_backendUrl->getUrl("the/url/path", $params);
    }
}
```

And in your phtml file write this

```
<form class="form" action="<?php echo $block->getPostUrl(); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: welcome back :-)

Comment: @KeyurShah in my form, form key available and field's name attribute also available. Still, $this->getRequest()->getPostValue() return blank. Do you know solution about that?

Comment: I added form in browser model dialogue. Same as like Catalog -> Categories -> Content -> Select From Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing an `input` with a form key!

I have had the same issue you're having multiple times.

Here's a way to get the form key:

`<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />`

You'll also need to get the URL for your `POST`. For that you need to utilize the function `getUrl()`

Let me know if this helps ya!